# How to run Node.JS and WAMP server same time for development a SPA?

Tags: php, node.js, angular, wampserver

I have been using AngularJS as my front-end framework and it has not been any issue because it is just a framework and we only have to link the AngualrJS core file (and routers if any) and other JS files in the header section of a HTML document using `.

But I wish to switch from AngularJS to **Angular 5** and noticed that we need to **run NodeJS first.** The back-end of my website run by PHP 7 and MySQL. I run WAMP server for running PHP. My question is that, is it possible to run both NodeJS and WAMP server sametime? Al long as they provide different localhost. Because **my files are with .php extension**. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. NodeJs and WAMP server can be run separately at the same time a both of them are standalone servers.

WAMP Server has a control panel where you can start/stop it whereas NodeJS can be started in the terminal window (in case of Linux/Mac) or Command Prompt window (in case of Windows).

So When you start the WAMP Server, you can open a terminal/command prompt at the side and start the NodeJS Server. But please make sure both the servers are configured to listen to different ports.